# How can I show the expected inequality

Tags: probability, means, slope

For any $x, \mu = E[x]$,

it has been mentioned that

$$E\left[ \frac{x^m - \mu^m}{x-\mu}\right] \gt m \mu^{m-1}.$$

How can we say this for all $x$ is somewhat confusing to me. I can understand it to be true for $x  >  \mu$.

Comment: I suspect that you've forgotten a $E[]$ somewhere in your inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=4$ and $X:\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{-1}{0.5}\,\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{0}{0.5}\right)$, i.e. $X$ is $-1$ with probability $\frac12$.

Then $\mu=EX=-\frac12$. So we have:
\begin{align} E\left[\frac{X^4-\mu^4}{X-\mu}\right]&=E\left[X^3+\mu X^2+ \mu^2X+\mu^3\right]\\
&=-\frac12+\left(-\frac12\cdot\frac12\right)+\left(\frac14\cdot-\frac12\right)+\left(-\frac18\right)\\
&=-1 < -\frac48 = 4\mu^{3},\end{align}

so the inequality doesn't hold for all $x$ and all $m$, as you suspected.

---

However, let $X$ be a positive random variable, and $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then by Jensen's inequality, because $f(x)=x^k$ is convex for $x>0$, we would have $E[X^k]>(EX)^k=\mu^k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, after using the difference of powers formula as before, we have:
$$E\left[X^{m-1}+\mu X^{m-2}+\dots+\mu^{m-2}X+\mu^{m-1}\right] >\mu^{m-1}+\dots+\mu^{m-1}=m\mu^{m-1},$$
so the inequality is correct for all positive $x$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not always true.  For example, if $m=2$, 
$$ \frac{x^2-\mu^2}{x-\mu} = x+\mu > 2 \mu^1\ \text{iff}\ x > \mu$$

Comment: Yes, I realised it now. The expectation was missing. Thanks for the help.